# C++ order of specifying base classes in derived class

Tags: c++

This may be a basic question but I haven't seen it anywhere.
In C++, suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B  {
public:
    void f();
};

class C  {
public:
    void f();
};

class D : public B, public C{
public:
    void f();
};

void B::f(){cout << "bbb" << endl;}
void C::f(){cout << "ccc" << endl;}
void D::f(){cout << "ddd" << endl;}

int main () {

B *d = new D;

delete d;
d->f();
return 0;
}
```

This works fine and outputs *"bbb"*. But if I were to switch the order of

```
class D : public B, public C{
```

to

```
class D : public C, public B{
```

I would get a *"Aborted (core dumped)"* error. What is the reason for this? Could someone further explain in what ways the order of the base classes matters?

I know this is multiple inheritance but I am avoiding the diamond problem so not sure what's going on.

Comment: You are avoiding the dreaded diamond by introducing undefined behavior. This doesn't sound like it takes you closer to a solution.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: please dont fix errors in your code after you got answers that tell you how to fix that errors. This makes not only the answers obsolete, but also your question. I changed it back to what it was before. If you made this by accident and you really want to change it, then at least dont do it silently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `B` is not polymorphic (e.g. does not provide any `virtual` methods). Hence the compiler assumes that that the dynamic type of the object that `d` points to is `B`, and it tries to delete memory based on the address of the that `B` object, which in no longer matches the address of the actual `D` object. It is as one would write:

```
D * d = new D;
delete static_cast<B *>(d);
```

Undefined behavior right there. Why it seems to work when the order of classes inherited by `D` is `B`, `C`, is that probably in your case the address of the `B` part of the `D` object happened to be identical to the address of the `D` object itself. There are no destructors (explicitly or implicitly) defined, so only a deallocation function was called, which probably accepted the pointer provided by the respective allocation function.

Note also that according to [[basic.life]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7)

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]. Otherwise, such a glvalue refers to allocated storage ([basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]), and using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined. The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - the glvalue is used to access the object, or
> - the glvalue is used to call a non-static member function of the object, or
> - the glvalue is bound to a reference to a virtual base class ([dcl.init.ref]), or
> - the glvalue is used as the operand of a dynamic_­cast or as the operand of typeid.

Therefore calling `d->f();` after `delete d;` in your code also causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The undefined behavior isn't invoked, by calling a *"method on an object which is destroyed"*. It's dereferencing an invalid pointer (which is part of calling the function) that causes undefined behavior.

Comment: But you *should* mention that the object is not to be accessed after de-allocation.

Comment: Thanks, amended my answer.

Comment: was the question changed in the meantime? Currently there is no "calling `d->f();` after `delete d`"

Answer (score 4):

It's *undefined behaviour*, pure and simple.

You can't use `d` once you've `delete`d it. Granted it's odd that it "works" one way and not the other, but that's the nature of *undefined behaviour*. (You can conject the reason by noting that in the first way the address of `D` is the address of `B` - note that your classes are not *polymorphic types* - , but in the second case it isn't. And the `delete` is merely releasing the memory, not immediately wiping it).

But really,

```
delete d;
d->f();
```

is not going to end well. Even if you do swap the order of those statements, you ought to make the base class destructors *virtual* so the correct memory is deleted.

`class D : public B, public C` and `class D : public C, public B`, amongst other things, exchanges the *order* in which the base classes are constructed when `D` is constructed.

Comment: Isn't the order of base classes used in overload resolution (as is required in this case)?

Comment: @IInspectable: yeah, your're correct. There are other differences. I've doctored the answer.

Comment: @IInspectable: Where do you see overload or overload resoution? I see exactly one function with a certain name (`f`) in each class. The derived `f` hides the base `f`. Where's the overload?

Comment: I had d->f(); before delete d; in my program but mistyped above. Fixed now. I got the error in my program with the correct ordering.

Comment: @domoremath: And what happens if you don't call `f`at all? Which line causes the crash?...

Comment: @conio UB is caused by the destruction. The base classes do not provided any virtual destructors.

Comment: @SebTu: O RLY? Thanks for letting me know! I wonder how'd you get that idea!

Comment: @conio If you look a bit behind the scenes it's clear that calling a non-virtual destructor through the wrong pointer type is not good. If the pointer pointing to the sub-object is not pointing to the start of the derived object (as in you crashing example), your memory allocator will tilt.  Even if the pointer points to the address of the overall object (as in your non-crashing example), only the destructor of the subobject will be executed, because the non-virtuality prevents the compiler from performing the lookup done in the case of virtual inheritance..

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Oh, *now* I see. Thank you so much for rephrasing is! What would I have done otherwise?... Now I feel silly for asking OP that question. I have no idea why I did that... (You do realize that the example wasn't mine, don't you? Neither the crashing nor the non-crashing nor any other example at all were given by me.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: We understand, what the issue is. The memory allocator (that allegedly is going to *"tilt"*) is most certainly not involved in this tragedy.

Comment: @IInspectable What makes you think the allocator is not involved? Did you try to print the address passed to `delete`  in the crashing case? What happens if you try to call C's `free`  with an address which was never `malloc`ed? Why should C++'s alocation behave any different?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: The issue is caused by the compiler that decides on a compliant class layout implementation. Whereever the memory allocator decides the object should go doesn't matter. The code will always call into the wrong function. (The allocator might potentially fail later; but it's moot to ponder about the behavior that follows undefined behavior.)

Comment: @IInspectable `delete d` does two things. **First,** it calls the destructor, which is UB. It will typically not crash though if at that address resides an object (even a sub-object) of the type the pointer points to -- after all, a destructor is just a function, and in the OP actually a NOP. **Second,** it tries to de-allocate the memory pointed to by `d` which will *typically fail* if that address was never obtained by a `new`. "Whereever the memory allocator decides the object should go doesn't matter": True. But whatever you try to *free* matters extremely.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I'd hate to repeat myself, but here it goes: *"it's moot to ponder about the behavior that follows undefined behavior"*. Besides, the destructor call in the OP is not a NOP. Following C++ language rules, the compiler did insert a (trivial) destructor.

Comment: @IInspectable That pondering answers the OP's question. Let the OP decide whether it's moot. Besides, what, in your opinion, does the compiler-generated destructor do?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: The auto-generated destructor is *"trivial"* (do I always need to repeat myself when talking to you?).

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately you are repeating an irrelevant statement. I contend that the destructor does nothing, and that the compiler will not even generate a function call for it. (I called that jokingly a "NOP".) That is important because if nothing is done, nothing can crash. No destructor is, in fact, called, which is why no destructor call is the cause of the crash. Whether *on the language level* a (trivial) destructor is "inserted" is not contradicting, but simply irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: *"No destructor is, in fact, called"* - A blunt statement, and like most blunt statements, it is wrong, too. This is a **potential** optimization a compiler can apply. Optimizations must not change the observable behavior. In this case, calling the wrong destructor is the observable behavior (which is undefined), and the optimization changes that. That's what matters. Your conclusions are written for a different program (one where no destructor is called). It's not the program we see in the OP. Anyway, my time has value. I'm off.